# How to multiply matrices?

Tags: matrices, rotations

I've written a java-programm(JOGL) and have my vertices from the object I want to draw on screen. I've read, when I want to rotate my object I must multiply the matrix of my object with the so-called "rotation-matrix". Link -> [rotationsmatrix](http://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/glRotate) . I don't know what I've done wrong by multiplying the two matrices. So please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any experience with linear algebra?

Comment: No. We can't see what you've done, and nor can we all speak German.

Comment: what is linear algebra?

Comment: @noName Linear Algebra is the study of *linear systems*.  A large part of a linear algebra class is properties of matrices and vectors, which would probably be useful for this type of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot read German, but I used Google translate.  Please forgive me if I've misunderstood your goal.

Your mistake was in your definition of the rotation matrix.  Because you are rotating the object around the positive $z$ axis, the $z$ coordinate should **not** change after the rotation.  The rotation matrix should be a $3\times3$ matrix, not a $4\times4$; the result should be a $3\times1$ column vector that describes a point, not a $4\times4$ matrix.

I will call $\vec M$ the original point vector and $\vec M'$ the rotated point vector.

Thus:
$$\vec M' = \mathbf R \vec M$$

We let $\vec M = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}$.

Because we are rotating *around the positive $z$-axis*, the rotation matrix is:
$$R = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}$$

Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\vec M' &= \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} \\
&= \pmatrix{x\cos\theta -y\sin\theta \\ x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta \\ z}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted the matrices. 4x4 is common for doing geometry in a projective space (enables handling of lines and planes offset from the origin).

Comment: But my object has a 4*4 matrix. In the first line it has the 4 x-values of the 4 vertices. In line 2 it has the 4 y-values of 4 the vertices. In the third line are the 4 z-values of the vertices. In the last line are 4 numbers, all have the value 1. And how does the 3*3-rotation-matrix looks like?

Comment: @noName Are you rotating a **solid**/shape or a point?  I don't know about how to rotate solids...

Comment: Thank you! It works, but can I replace the rotation point? If yes, how?

Comment: @noName I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @anorton What do you think is the way to replace the rotation points?

Comment: @noName To replace the rotation point with a point $X$ (represented by a vector), I would compute $(M - X)R + X$  That's just a guess though, and I haven't written it out at all to make sure.

Comment: How must I multiply the other rotation-matrices(for x- or y-axis-rotation)? It doesn't works, if I multiply it on the same way.